# What oauth grant type should I use after social sign in

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have an application which has its own oauth microservice to issue access tokens. For users registering using email and password I am using grant_type = 'password'. What should I do when a users signs in using social media?

I thought of generating a random password for getting access tokens, but the oauth server  accepts only plain text passwords and I am storing password as hashes in my db. Should I be using a different grant type to get tokens?

Comment: is oauth server written in spring-boot? If yes, are you allowed to make change in oauth server?

Comment: Everything is written in nodejs and I can make changes to oauth server. Please refer to this question for a clearer explanation https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/193987/what-oauth-grant-type-should-i-use-after-social-sign-in

Comment: I have achieved flow what you are expecting using spring-boot(i have overridden some of the class which is responsible for generating access/refresh token). Not sure if you can use same since you have everything in nodejs.